# А это что значит?

Tags: php

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for links(), called in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\function.php on line 12 and defined in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\function.php on line 26

Warning: Missing argument 2 for links(), called in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\function.php on line 12 and defined in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\function.php on line 26
```

Квадрат 325 равен - 105625Онлайн игра!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
<title>Функции</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

links();
echo "<br>";

function square($a)
{
$result = $a*$a;
echo $result;
}
$e = 325;

echo "Квадрат $e равен - ";

square(325);

function links($links,$title)
{
echo "<a href='$links'>$title</a>";
}
links('http://clv.hol.es','Онлайн игра!');

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Алексей31, что links должен вызваться с двумя аргументами, чего не происходит в первом случае.

Comment: Это значит, что нужно читать текст ошибки, а если трудно с языком, то хотя бы в гугл транслейт вбить.

Comment: Все, разобрался, Слава Богу! Учение php даеться не всем легко, но все же приятно, когда начинаешь хоть в чем-то разбираться! Еще раз спасибо вам!

Comment: @Алексей31, у вас из "начинаешь" мягкий знак убежал в "дается"